Bootstrap 5 закрывать мобильное меню при нажатии на ссылку
Бутстрап меню 5 версия.
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/images/logo.svg" height="54"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor04" aria-controls="navbarColor04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarColor04" style="">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item ms-lg-2">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Главная</a>
                </li>
                <li>...ссылка на якорь...</li>
                <li>...ссылка на якорь...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

В мобильной версии при нажатии на ссылку на якорь, страница прокручивается, но меню не захлопывается, мешая просмотру страницы. Как сделать, чтобы оно закрывалось при нажатии на любой .nav-link?
<script>
    $('.nav-link').on('click', function () {
       $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('show');
    }


Это не помогает.

Попробуй это:
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/images/logo.svg" height="54"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor04" aria-controls="navbarColor04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarColor04" style="">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ms-lg-2">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Главная</a>
            </li>
            <li>...ссылка на якорь...</li>
            <li>...ссылка на якорь...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.nav-link').on('click', function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
        });
    });
</script>

